# What are these mysterious borders in a TTableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, three20

I have the following hierarchy in an IO application:

```
. TTTableViewController, with the following elements
.. @""
.. TTTableCaptionItem
.. @""
.. TTTableSubtitleItemCell
.. @""
.. TTTableTextItem
.. @""
.. (other cells)
.. TTTableViewItem
 ... TTTableViewController
```

This shows "mystery borders" around the embedded TTTableViewController which I can't seem to get rid of.

[image]

The embedded TableViewItem's initialization is completely vanilla:

```
@implementation DetailCommentsItemCell
   - (id) initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
    {
      if (self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle  reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier])
      {
      }
      return self;
    }
- (void)setObject:(id)object {
  _item = object;
  [self.contentView addSubview:[[object commentsViewController] tableView]];
}
```

(The "commentsViewController" is the embedded TTTableViewController)

Does anyone know what these borders are and how to get rid of them?

By request, here's the set up code for the table:

```
    - (id)initWithFilter:(ObjectId)parameter_filter detailViewController:(DetailViewController  *)dvp;
   {
      DDLogInfo(@"CommentsViewController::initWithFilter parameter_filter %llu",
                parameter_filter);

      if (self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped])
      {

        self.tableView.clipsToBounds = YES;
        self.variableHeightRows = YES;
      }
      return self;
    }
```

Update:

At @rishi's excellent suggest I added

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.tableView.backgroundView = nil;
```

This is much better but I still have an artifact. See below:

[image]

Another Update: I added the following code:

```
self.tableView.layer.borderColor      = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
self.tableView.layer.backgroundColor  = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
```

Now it looks like this:

[image]

It seems like it's the layer that is the culprit - but I can't get rid of the border - if that's what it is.

As an experiment, I set the border of the containing cell's layer to 2, and Red. Here's what I get, which tells me the mystery border is associated with the table, not it's surrounding cell:

[image]

This is ODD. I looked at it in a Retina display, and the "border" is actually the border of some object BEHIND the table.

[image]

FINAL UPDATE:

That artifact turned out to be the border of the table cell the inner TableViewItem was embedded in. The cells were offset due to an inset adjustment I'd made, but I'd failed to adjust the y origin correctly.

Thanks to everyone for their help!

Comment: can you add some code of table view creation and cellforrow method?

Comment: I've added the TableView creation. Are you referring o the cellforrow for the main table or the embedded table? There are actually NO Cell For Row methods in either - I'm using Three20 Custom cells.

Comment: I think there might be a problem in frames..frames of custom cells might be comparable to tableview frame check..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following code in `initWithFilter` method-

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.tableView.backgroundView = nil;
```

Comment: That got rid of the borders, but now I have a new artifact? Image added to original question. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelWilson - can you code if cellForRowAtIndexPath  method?

Comment: Sure. And then it would do what? :-)

Comment: lets try to find the solution first :)

Comment: @MichaelWilson - try doing one more quick thing , set self.tableView.backgroundView = YES, at the same place where you put earlier code.

Comment: That crashes instantly, since "YES" isn't a good pointer. I added another update above.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11234/discussion-between-rishi-and-michael-wilson)